# Exporting Excel Range as image (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba, charts

I have a working excel vba macro that does what I want from [here](http://snipplr.com/view/54755/) and I am trying to convert it to VB.NET.

The code from VBA:

```
Sub bah()
''' Set Range you want to export to file
    Dim rgExp As Range: Set rgExp = Range("B2:C6")
    ''' Copy range as picture onto Clipboard
    rgExp.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, format:=xlBitmap
    ''' Create an empty chart with exact size of range copied
    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=rgExp.Left, Top:=rgExp.Top, _
    Width:=rgExp.Width, Height:=rgExp.Height)
    .Name = "ChartVolumeMetricsDevEXPORT"
    .Activate
    End With
    ''' Paste into chart area, export to file, delete chart.
    ActiveChart.Paste
   ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("ChartVolumeMetricsDevEXPORT").Chart.Export "C:\Users\ajohnson\Desktop\workdamnit.jpg"
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("ChartVolumeMetricsDevEXPORT").Delete
End Sub
```

What this does is take an excel range and then put it into a chart that is a copy of the range and save it as a JPG.

Here is my most recent attempt at making it VB.NET:

```
Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim xlRange As Excel.Range
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\test.xlsx")
xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")


 xlRange = xlWorkSheet.Range("B2:C6")
        With xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects.add(xlRange.Left, xlRange.Top, xlRange.Width, xlRange.Height)
            .name = "Chart1"
            .activate()
        End With
xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects("Chart1").Paste()
        xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects("Chart1").chart.export(Filename:="C:\Users\ajohnson\Desktop\saveit.jpg")
        xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects("Chart1").delete()
```

I am running into trouble converting the `ActiveChart.Paste` method. I can't get it to work in VB.NET. It either throws an error or It just leaves an empty box when I do it in VB.NET (if I add `.chart` before the paste it runs, but doesn't paste any values), but in VBA it fills in the values of interest. I have tried creating a chart object, but that did not seem to work either.

I feel like I am close to having it sorted out, but I can't quite get it. I suppose I could leave it as a VBA macro and call it from VB.NET, but that seems absurd on some level. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am also open to different approaches, its just this is the thing I came across that worked well in VBA, so I figured it was a good starting point.

Thanks as always!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just had to hit the MSDN up a little harder to get there. Turns out you have to put the chartobject inside a chart, the code I got working looks like:

```
  xlRange = xlWorkSheet.Range("B2:C6")
    xlRange.CopyPicture(Excel.XlPictureAppearance.xlScreen, Excel.XlCopyPictureFormat.xlPicture)
    Dim oChtobj As Excel.ChartObject = xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects.add(xlRange.Left, xlRange.Top, xlRange.Width, xlRange.Height)
    Dim oCht As Excel.Chart
    oCht = oChtobj.Chart
    oCht.Paste()
    oCht.Export(Filename:="C:\saveit.jpg")
    oChtobj.Delete()
```

I was going to delete the question, since it got solved by me so quickly (this ignores the decent bit of time I spent before I posted it here), but when I search for a problem like mine it comes to this page, so maybe this will help someone in the future. If you are looking to copy a range from excel to a jpg for some reason (perhaps attaching it to the body of an outlook email, because that is what I am doing), this should work for you.

Comment: It is also worth noting that you will have to delete the chart object to be able to do this multiple times, otherwise it will trip up. oChtobj.Delete() is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

And the C# equivalent requires the call to Activate() or COMException will be thrown

```cs
Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorkSheet.Range("B2:C6");

range.CopyPicture(Excel.XlPictureAppearance.xlScreen, Excel.XlCopyPictureFormat.xlPicture);
Excel.ChartObject chartObj = myWorksheet.ChartObjects().Add(range.Left, range.Top, range.Width, range.Height);

chartObj.Activate();  // Don't Forget!

Excel.Chart chart = chartObj.Chart;
chart.Paste();
chart.Export(@"C:\image.png");

chartObj.Delete();
```